# Javascript Injection - Change text field size

Tags: javascript

I have to use a special form for work and the form has a comment section that is WAY too small (about 5 lines for 30+ lines of text) Since the developers don't update the software very often, I usually take the initiative to create bookmarklets that do what I want.

I'm trying to create a javascript line that extends the size of the textbox. I am taking this approach but it does not work:

```
    javascript:document.getElementById("CommentArea").style.height="700px";
```

Form name is "Survey" if that helps.

Any ideas?

(Note: I'm trying to change the visual size, not the character limit.)

Comment: Are you adding that snippet to the address bar? Why?

Answer (score 2):

[`Textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/textarea)s use the `rows` attribute to determine the `number of visible text lines for the control`:

```
​document.getElementById("test").rows = 20;​
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DbSxa/)**

Comment: That sounds right but it is not working. It takes me to a blank page with the text "20" at the top. I'm guessing there's something going on with the actual form as it is full of enormous amounts of javascript.  Thank you for the help, I think "rows" is what I was looking for.

Comment: I believe so as well, but I'm not too sure why it's not working for you. If I think of anything I'll definitely let you know and if you find anything else out please post it here and I'll update the answer for future searchers.